# Cint and Cdbl not working on Swedish Keyboard

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm facing a strange issue where Cint and Cdbl are not returning expected output on Swedish keyboard. They work fine on English keyboard.

```
Cint("6.0")    # Output: 60
Cdbl("70.8")    # Output: 708
```

For some reason, both the functions are removing the decimal from string.

Comment: try replacing dot with comma

Comment: it works that way but the problem is these values are picked at run time and the same code is supposed to work in both Swedish and English region settings.

Comment: CInt and CLong (and other C* functions) use the system locale settings for type conversion. Val() on the other hand always use the "." as decimal separator, so if you are sure to always have only the dot as input you can replace CDbl by Val.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - this one is not available in `vba`, only in `vbscript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA use `Val`, which always assume dot as decimal separator.

In VBScript, I use to solve this question using:

```
CDbl(Replace(number_in_string, ".", Mid(1.3, 2, 1)))
```

This way numeric 1.3 is converted into a localized string and decimal separator extracted from 2rd character. Then, dot in supplied string is replaced by decimal separator extracted.

Possible issues:

1. Thousand separators! If your number use thousand separators that are the same of your system decimal separator, convertion will get corrupt! Example: `"1,234.56"` will become  `"1,234,56"`! Workaround: 
   `CDbl(Replace(Replace(number_in_string, ",", ""), ".", Mid(1.3, 2, 1))) 'Remove comma thousand separator`
2. Number formating: assuming `1.3` will become a string where decimal separator is in 2nd character is not acquired for sure!

Comment: Brilliant!! I used a similar way that you've mentioned for VBS but to get the separator, I used `GetLocale` to check if it is Swedish and then provide the "," separator.